# MODULE doesn't work - unknown mutation type: user/setUserInfo

Tags: javascript, vue.js, module, vuex

Here is my store/index.js

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    app,
    user,
  },
  state: {
    token: getToken(),
    hasLogin: false,
  },
  mutations: {
    ...rootMutations,
  },
  actions: {
    ...rootActions,
  },
})

export default store
```

store/modules/user.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    phone: '',
  },
  mutations: {
    setUserInfo(
        { state },
        { phone },
    ) {
      // ...
      state.phone = phone | state.phone
    },
  },
})

export default store
```

and here is the Action went wrong

rootActions.js

```js
const actions = {
getUserInfo: async function(store) {
    const { commit, state } = store
    console.log(store)
    return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            // a lot of request code, save results in user/setUserInfo

            commit('login')
            commit('user/setUserInfo', {
              phone: r.phone,
            })
    })
  },
}
```

then something wrong with the alert

```
[vuex] unknown mutation type: user/setUserInfo(env: macOS,mp,1.05.2106300; lib: 2.17.0)
```

I don't know why I can not access mutations in user module, I've search a lot of sample that accessing root mutation from module and it seems doesn't work for me.

can anyone help solve this plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not create new instance of vuex store for each module. you need to export the object that contains the `state`, `actions`, `mutations` and `actions`.

so your `user.js` file should look like this:

```js
export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    phone: '',
  },
  mutations: {
    setUserInfo(
        state,
        { phone },
    ) {
      // ...
      state.phone = phone | state.phone
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! It solves my problem perfectly. And params in setUserInfo should not be `{ state }`, it should be just `state`.